# Is there a more efficient way to represent my string containing image pixel data as an image mask?

Tags: python

I'm representing image pixel data as a string.

For example, let's say an image is 2x2 pixels, the string would be 4 characters long since we have 4 pixels.
So if the string is 0100 (where 1 is a white pixel), what I basically want to achieve is to create an image mask from this string.

NOTE: I do not have to use 1's and 0's as representation for my pixels. This is just for use as an example. It could be x and y or any other combination of characters, but the string will only contain two distinct characters. For example, I could have 'bwwb' where b represents a black pixel and w is a white pixel.

The data being a string is also just the way that it is being received as input to python. I am allowed to convert it into a numpy array or other formats.

With the order that the pixel data in my string is stored, bwwb would look like this if represented as a matrix:

```
w b
b w
```

Similarly for a 3x3 image with string 'wbbbwbwbw', the image matrix would look like this:

```
w b w
b w b 
w b b
```

I am currently using this method to generate the image mask:

```
    mask = np.zeros((height,width,3), dtype=np.uint8)

    for ph in range(height):
        for pw in range(width):
            index = ph + pw
            pixel_value = pixel_string[index]

            if pixel_value == 'w':
                mask[ph,pw] = 255
```

Using nested loops is too slow for my needs however. I was wondering if there are more efficient ways to achieve this, maybe in numpy or cv2?

Comment: Are  you using the correct terms here? A mask is a layer that is used to effect some kind of filtering of other image data, that does not appear to be the case here? As for "more efficient": if you just need ones and zeroes, use bits, not "the letters 1 and 0"? your 0100 would just be the nibble 0x4 and your 011100011 would be 0xE3. You might need a variable length encoded value that says how many bits to look at before the actual bits themselves, but there's plenty of pages on the web explaining how to do that.

Comment: I agree with Mike - representing pixels of image data as a string is not a great idea to begin with. 

Why not store it in a numpy array or something similar - those you can easily reshape.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Mask probably isn't the best word for this question, but it is correct for my application. I'm doing computer vision. The pixel string corresponds to a mask. The letters 1 and 0 are just for example purposes to show what I'm doing.

Comment: @Chris This string data is being piped from another process to python. I could convert it to a numpy array, in which case what functions can I use to achieve the desired representation?

Comment: Never use things "for example purposes" without fully describing what it's an example of. Can the values be more than 0 or 1? How _much_ more? These are _critical_ details that [are currently missing and you should add to your post](/help/how-to-ask) because they change what the correct answer(s) can be =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I edited my post to clarify

Answer (score 0):

To answer the your question of the comments

```
a = "0 1 1 0"
b = np.fromstring(a, dtype=int, sep=" ")
b.reshape(int(len(b)/2), int(len(b)/2))
```

something like this e.g --> results in:

```
array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
```